# Convert asynchronous call with events to synchronous in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a component that is assigned a task to perform asynchronously. When it is done, it will fire one of two events to denote success or failure. I need to convert all this to a synchronous call:

```
Public Function AssignTask(o As Object) as Boolean
    Dim component As New X.Y.Z.Component()
    component.DoSomethingWith(o)
    AddHandler component.OnSuccess, AddressOf OnSuccess
    AddHandler component.OnError, AddressOf OnError

    Return True 'Need to return success or not.
End Sub

Private Sub OnSuccess(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    'Success! :)
End Sub

Private Sub OnError(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    'Error! :(
End Sub
```

I am confused, as of how to I get the events to trigger success or failure to the main method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (this is not thread safe, so won't play well if you call this for different threads)

```
Private _completedFlag As Boolean
Private _completionResult As Boolean

Public Function AssignTask(o As Object) as Boolean
    Dim component As New X.Y.Z.Component()
    _completedFlag = False
    AddHandler component.OnSuccess, AddressOf OnSuccess
    AddHandler component.OnError, AddressOf OnError
    component.DoSomethingWith(o)
    Do Until _completedFlag
        'wait
    Loop
    Return _completionResult
End Sub

Private Sub OnSuccess(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    _completionResult = True
    _completedFlag = True
End Sub

Private Sub OnError(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    _completionResult = False
    _completedFlag = True
End Sub
```

I have moved the AddHandler to before you actually call the method, as it is possible that it completes before the handler is attached

Comment: Thank you! Neat and simple solution.